# Use a custom allocator with boost::bimap

Tags: c++, boost, memory-pool, bimap

I am working on improving the performance of a program which uses both the Boost Graph Library and `boost::bimap`. Profiling revealed that most of the time was being spent in memory allocation and deallocation.  Making the `adjacency_list` class of the graph library use `boost::fast_pool_allocator` improved performance significantly.  A large chunk of the remaining memory allocations occur in `boost::bimap`, so I wanted to experiment with using a custom allocator there as well.  The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/complete_instantiation_scheme.html) says you can specify the allocator as the last template parameter of the bimap, but it does not say what type the template argument to the allocator itself should be.  For example, for types `X` and `Y`, in

```
boost::bimap<set_of<X>, set_of<Y>, boost::fast_pool_allocator<Z> >
```

what should be filled in for `Z`?

Comment: I would strongly recommend not using boost:bimap. Using a boost multi-index container with two indices directly is much clearer than code that uses a bimap.

Comment: @Autopulated: Thank you - I will consider that alternative next time I would otherwise try a bimap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is that for `Z`, you should fill in `std::pair<X,Y>`.  This worked in my case, but I wanted to post here because

- it's not obvious from the documentation
- Boost code is not quick to read
- Googling was unhelpful
- and other people might have useful comments (for instance, I haven't tested if this depends on what the left or right view of the bimap is)